# Как из String JSON получить String anotherJSON, который он содержит

Tags: java, json, веб-программирование, экранирование

Я получаю `String jsonObject` в контроллере. Структура файла следующая:

```
{
"name":"name", 
"schema": {
   ... 
   ...
   }
}
```

Мне нужно распарсить его в pojo и получить `"schema"` как строку (сохраняя структуру). Т.е. при `System.out.print("schema")` я должен увидеть:

```
{
...
... 
}
```

Я создал класс *Collection* с полями `String name` и `Object schema` и использую GSON чтобы получить *Collection.class* из `String json`:

`new Gson().fromJson(json, Collection.class);`

Но когда я пытаюсь вызвать `System.out.print(Collection.schema)` я получаю следующий вывод:

`{......}` - в одну строку.

Мне действительно нужно получить этот объект в качестве строки **без форматирования**.

Comment: я вас правильно понимаю, вы хотите чтоб в JSON был отформатированный текст?

Comment: да, с переносами строки и прочими радостями

Comment: Не подскажите для чего? JSON это формат для обмена информацией с сервисом. Если вы хотите просто распечатать объект в строку, переопределите метод toString() в объекте и сформируйте в нем ту строку которую хотите получить с переносами и т.д.

Comment: Этот объект - json схема, по которой должен проверяться json объект.  При помощи сторонних библиотек мне нужно передать строку jsonObject и строку jsonSchema - и она вернет true или false. Так вот, если копипастом передаю в java, она экранирует и все работает отлично. Если поломать структуру, то при создании объекта при помощи либы вылетит экспешн - она даже не признает в нем json структуру

Comment: в контроллере json я могу получить как строку из body запроса. Но из json мне нужно вытащить его параметр "schema" и вот его значение получить как строку.

Comment: я вас правильно понимаю, вы откуда-то получили строку JSON, вы создаете объект в который должна распарситься эта строка при помощи библиотеки GSON. На выходе вы получаете уже заполненный объект. В этом объекте меняете те атрибуты которые вам необходимо. Если хотите его распечатать переопределяете в этом объекте toString() и печатаете так как вам надо. Вы не должны работать со строками JSON напрямую, вы меняете объекты, если надо потом просто опять переводите его в JSON формат.

Comment: Да. Я получил строку JSON и распарсил через GSON в объект. Допустим, JSON состоит из строки, числа и объекта_json - "schema": {..многострочный код...}. В java после парсинга я получу некий объект с полями int, String и Object. Если для этого json объекта я укажу тип String, а не Object, будет ошибка парсинга. Если укажу Object, то при вызове на нем toString() многострочный код объекта из json'a превратиться в одну строку. Мне же нужно получить String = "{...многострочный код json объекта..}"; а я имею String = "{..тот же код в одну строку"}";

Comment: дополнил в UPDATE визуальное отображение

Comment: Создайте не Object, а объект конкретного типа скажем Schema. Структуру этого объекта опишите отдельным классом.

Comment: Тогда я должен описать класс schema, а откуда я заранее узнаю структуру? И она может каждый раз быть отличной

Comment: переписал вопрос в формализованном виде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Пример использования

```
public static void main(String[]args){
            String jsonStr = "{\"id\":1,\"title\":\"Yellow Submarine\",\"releaseDate\":\"1969-01-17\",\"artist\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"The Beatles\"},\"label\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Apple\"}}";
            System.out.println(formatJSON(jsonStr));
        }
public static String formatJSON(String jsonStr) {
    String str="";
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Object json = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Object.class);
        str = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return str;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете почитать более подробно [здесь](https://kodejava.org/how-to-pretty-print-json-string-using-jackson/)

Comment: этот объект всегда рандомный, я не знаю в каком месте ставить все переносы, разве что досканально изучить структуру json объектов и написать универсальный инструмент для этого, но думаю должны быть готовые решения

Comment: JSON имеет определенную структуру и в ней нет ничего хитрого, можно самому отформатировать. Пример добавил в ответ

Comment: я поправил ответ

Comment: Проблему решил перегнав Object обратно в json при помощи того же GSON. Возможно ваш пример лучше подойдет, надо будет протестировать. Спасибо вам большое